# How to start tomcat7 when catalina.sh does not work?

Tags: apache2, configuration, software-installation, tomcat

I installed tomcat7 via the command `sudo apt-get install tomcat7`,
now I went to `/usr/share/tomcat7/bin` and inputted `catalina.sh` but the following error occured

```
Cannot find /home/mukund/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/setclasspath.sh
This file is needed to run this program
```

What did I wrong? How to start apache tomcat? Please give the solution in step by step
Thanks

Comment: Did you edit your `catalina.sh`? If you do, please post it here.

Comment: no nothing, didint do anything, just installed by sudo cammand, searched where it is installed, found catalina.sh and typed ./catalina.sh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install tomcat7, you have nothing to type to start it. It starts up automatically. Notice in install log:

```
$ sudo apt-get install tomcat7
...
Creating config file /etc/logrotate.d/tomcat7 with new version
 * Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomcat7                                [ OK ]
Setting up authbind (2.1.1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
```

So, to test it, you have to write in browser `http://localhost:8080`. And you will see the page:

> ## It works !
>
> If you're seeing this page via a web browser, it means you've setup
>   Tomcat successfully. Congratulations!
>
> This is the default
>   Tomcat home page. It can be found on the local filesystem at:
>   `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/index.html`
>
> Tomcat7 veterans might be pleased to learn that this system
>   instance of Tomcat is installed with `CATALINA_HOME` in
>   `/usr/share/tomcat7` and `CATALINA_BASE` in
>   `/var/lib/tomcat7`, following the rules from
>   `/usr/share/doc/tomcat7-common/RUNNING.txt.gz`.
>
> You might consider installing the following packages, if you
>   haven't already done so:
>
> **tomcat7-docs**: This package installs a web application that
>   allows to browse the Tomcat 7 documentation locally. Once installed,
>   you can access it by clicking here.
>
> **tomcat7-examples**: This package installs a web application
>   that allows to access the Tomcat 7 Servlet and JSP examples. Once
>   installed, you can access it by clicking here.
>
> **tomcat7-admin**: This package installs two web applications
>   that can help managing this Tomcat instance. Once installed, you can
>   access the manager webapp and the host-manager webapp.
>
> NOTE: For security reasons, using the manager webapp is restricted
>   to users with role "manager-gui". The host-manager webapp is
>   restricted to users with role "admin-gui". Users are defined in
>   `/etc/tomcat7/tomcat-users.xml`.

To start/stop Tomcat, use `service tomcat7 start/stop/restart`:

```
$ sudo service tomcat7 stop
 * Stopping Tomcat servlet engine tomcat7                                [ OK ] 
$ sudo service tomcat7 start
 * Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomcat7                                [ OK ]
```

Comment: and i tried to connect the apache tomcat server 127.0.1.1:8080 via web browsers, its works, i tried the same with android emulator, its not connectiong, how to make it connect?

Comment: i tried 10.0.2.2, there is also an issue, if you try localhost/index.html, problem loading page is occuring, any configuration issues?

Comment: Probably you should ask another question or come into chat.

Comment: yes i did check http://askubuntu.com/questions/446333/connecting-to-tomcat7-from-android-emulator