# connecting to tomcat7 from android emulator

Tags: networking, android, emulation, tomcat7

I can connect to apache server from chrome and firefox by typing `127.0.1.1:8080` and default page is shown, but when i type the same from my android emulator, no webpage is loaded, request timeout error, also if I try to connect via typing `localhost` this page is shown:

```
problem loading page
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost
```

What is wrong with my localhost?

I also tried `10.0.2.2` from android emulator, still can't connect.

What is wrong here? Is my localhost switched? How to fix it? Please help
Thanks

Comment: Did you try to type `10.0.2.2:8080`? Is the `10.0.2.2` your host address as it seen from android emulator?

Comment: yes i did, still no result, my question is that why i cant see localhost in firefox browser?

Comment: You can't see it because it is _another localhost_. I'm trying to figure out what host is correct so I will post the helpful answer.

Comment: please be hurry, and one more thing, i had apache2 installed, and when it was  there, giving localhost/index.html gave me a page saying 'It Works' along with something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't see it because it is *another localhost*. To determine valid host's IP just ping your host's name from Android Emulator.

```
ping mukund
```

It should return you address like `192.168.X.Y` or `10.0.X.Y`. This is the correct address on which you should go with your browser.

Also, `ifconfig` should show you the external (as it seems to AE) IP of your machine:

```
$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:03:99:8a:3b:ee  
          inet addr:10.0.0.125  Bcast:10.0.3.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::203:99ff:fe8a:3bee/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4579990 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:1 frame:0
          TX packets:668167 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:880972560 (880.9 MB)  TX bytes:63991366 (63.9 MB)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0x8c00 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:35718 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:35718 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:3293586 (3.2 MB)  TX bytes:3293586 (3.2 MB)
```

So, in my case, specifying `10.0.0.125:8080` in the AE should return the right page. The `ifconfig` command is also available in Android. Execute it to see the broadcast address of internal LAN.

And if you still can't determine your IP, execute this inside AE:

```
ping -b <broadcast>
```

It will return all available addresses. You should choose the one appropriate.